# NSXMLParser: How to display the response obtained from webservice?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xml, ios4, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to parse my data obatained from my webservice. But when I get the data from the server.

It gives me Error Code 5.

I am not able to see the response that comes from the webservice.

I use

```
 NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL];
```

But I cannot see the response in console when I write `NSLog(@"%@",parser);`

How can I display the response obtained from my webservice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Data returned from a URL is usually just text. It may also be XML, but you can see the raw response by using the following:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theURL
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                     error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"response: %@", string);
}
```

Comment: Thank you e.James I will check out your answer and get back to you soon

Answer (score 0):

With the error code 5 means , your xml was not well formed.
Ans  as far as your xml output concerned , you had to implement the nsxmlparserdelegate methods to get the xml parsed check the tutorials on the same topic..